# Regex for converting xml tags key to camel case

Tags: java, regex, xml, string

I am looking for the simplest method in java which takes a XML string, and converts all tags (not their contents) to camel case, such as

```
<HeaderFirst>
  <HeaderTwo>
        <ID>id1</ID>
         <TimeStamp>2016-11-04T02:46:34Z</TimeStamp>
         <DetailedDescription>
            <![CDATA[di]]>
         </DetailedDescription>
  </HeaderTwo> 
</HeaderFirst>
```

will be converted to

```
<headerFirst>
  <headerTwo>
        <id>id1</id>
         <timeStamp>2016-11-04T02:46:34Z</timeStamp>
         <detailedDescription>
            <![CDATA[di]]>
         </detailedDescription>
  </headerTwo> 
</headerFirst>
```

Comment: Find patterns that match Strings within angle brackets such as "<[a-zA-Z]+>" and from there subString to find and replace the second or third String depending on starting or ending tag. Maybe an if check to see if substring[1] is "/".

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
public void tagToCamelCase(String input){
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length-2; i++){
            if (inputArray[i] == '<'){
                if(inputArray[i+1]!= '/')
                    inputArray[i+1] = Character.toLowerCase(inputArray[i+1]);
                else
                    inputArray[i+2] = Character.toLowerCase(inputArray[i+2]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new String(inputArray));
}
```

Note: the tag ID will be iD and not id. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution that is based on splitting the string on the ">" character and then processing the tokens in three different cases: CDATA, open tag, and close tag

The following code should work (see the program output below).  There is, however, a problem with the tag "ID" -- how do we know that its camel case should be "id" not "iD"?  This needs a dictionary to capture that knowledge.  So the following routine convert() has two modes -- useDictionary being true or false.  See if the following solution satisfies your requirement.

To use the "useDictionary" mode you also need to maintain a proper dictionary (the hashmap called "dict" in the program, right now there is only one entry in the dictionary "ID" should be camel-cased to "id").  **Note that the dictionary can be ramped up incrementally** -- you only need to add the special cases to the dictionary (e.g. the camel-case of "ID" is "id" not "iD")

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CamelCase {
    private static Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        dict.put("ID", "id");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "<HeaderFirst> "
                + "\n  <HeaderTwo>"
                + "\n        <ID>id1</ID>"
                + "\n         <TimeStamp>2016-11-04T02:46:34Z</TimeStamp>"
                + "\n         <DetailedDescription>"
                + "\n            <![CDATA[di]]>"
                + "\n         </DetailedDescription>"
                + "\n  </HeaderTwo>  "
                + "\n</HeaderFirst>";
        System.out.println("===== output without using a dictionary =====");
        System.out.println(convert(input, false /* useDictionary */));
        System.out.println("===== output using a dictionary =====");
        System.out.println(convert(input, true /* useDictionary */));
    }

    private static String convert(String input, boolean useDictionary) {
        String splitter = ">";
        String[] tokens = input.split(splitter);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Pattern cdataPattern = Pattern.compile("([^<]*)<!\\[CDATA\\[([^\\]]*)\\]\\]");
        Pattern oTagPattern  = Pattern.compile("([^<]*)<(\\w+)");
        Pattern cTagPattern  = Pattern.compile("([^<]*)</(\\w+)");

        String prefix;
        String tag;
        String newTag;
        for (String token : tokens) {
            Matcher cdataMatcher = cdataPattern.matcher(token);
            Matcher oTagMatcher  = oTagPattern.matcher(token);
            Matcher cTagMatcher  = cTagPattern.matcher(token);
            if (cdataMatcher.find()) {      // CDATA - do not change
                sb.append(token);
            } else if (oTagMatcher.find()) {// open tag - change first char to lower case
                prefix  = oTagMatcher.group(1);
                tag     = oTagMatcher.group(2);
                newTag = camelCaseOneTag(tag, useDictionary);
                sb.append(prefix + "<" + newTag);
            } else if (cTagMatcher.find()) {// close tag - change first char to lower case
                prefix  = cTagMatcher.group(1);
                tag     = cTagMatcher.group(2);
                newTag = camelCaseOneTag(tag, useDictionary);
                sb.append(prefix + "<" + newTag);
            } 
            sb.append(splitter);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String camelCaseOneTag(String tag, boolean useDictionary) {
        String newTag;
        if (useDictionary 
                && dict.containsKey(tag)) {
            newTag = dict.get(tag);
        } else {
            newTag = tag.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase()
                    + tag.substring(1);
        }
        return newTag;      
    }
}
```

The output of this program is this:

```
===== output without using a dictionary =====
<headerFirst> 
  <headerTwo>
        <iD>id1<iD>
         <timeStamp>2016-11-04T02:46:34Z<timeStamp>
         <detailedDescription>
            <![CDATA[di]]>
         <detailedDescription>
  <headerTwo>  
<headerFirst>
===== output using a dictionary =====
<headerFirst> 
  <headerTwo>
        <id>id1<id>
         <timeStamp>2016-11-04T02:46:34Z<timeStamp>
         <detailedDescription>
            <![CDATA[di]]>
         <detailedDescription>
  <headerTwo>  
<headerFirst>
```